# Google Awareness Snapshot API deprecated alternatives

Tags: android, deprecated, google-awareness

Notice: The Places and Weather contextual signals (exposed via the getPlaces(), and getWeather() methods), are deprecated as of August 7, 2019.

I have app using this 2 methods, I searched for alternative to it and I found that I might use "Radar" for places, but I didn't find anything for the weather. Can you suggest me a good alternative to the "old" Snapshot API?

Answer (score 0):

You could try OpenWeatherMap or yahoo Api. 
In the free version, both have a limited number of calls, you should check if they are sufficient for your application, otherwise you have to switch to the paid versions.